# Filtering Django models by existence of a related object

Tags: django, django-models

Consider the following Django models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    color = models.CharField()
```

Users might have many notes of different colors. What is the best way to fetch the following query:

> Get me all notes but only for users which have at least one note which is red

The naive way would be to fetch the list of users which have at least one red note and then do a filter on the notes with `user__in=long_list`, but this seems awkward. The solution seems to be around excluding any user without a single red note, but I'm not seeing how this should be done.

Additionally, this query will run on very large sets of users and notes, and must be performant.

What would be the right way to do this, without resorting to native SQL, unless absolutely neccesary?

Comment: @karthikr, that will only bring red notes. Read my description carefully.

Comment: would https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter users using the backward relation from users to notes, lets try something like this

```
Note.objects.filter(user__note__color='red')
```

Comment: Again, that will only fetch red notes, read the description again.

Comment: @YuvalAdam no it won't. why should it do that? It fetches all Notes related to a User who has a Note with color=red, which is exactly what you ask.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Intuitively it seems equivalent to `Note.objects.filter(color='red')` but I might be wrong. Testing.

Comment: MIND. BLOWN. It works, I definitely have some homework to do. Thanks!!

Comment: Just for information, in term of performance isn't it the same than fetch the list of users which have at least one red note and then do a filter on the notes with user__in=long_list?

Comment: @trnsnt, no because in that case you are fetching a preliminary set of objects, which goes over the wire twice, and is useless after that.

Comment: @Yuval Adam, yes you're right. Django is smarter than I thought!